# Concurrency issues with observable.observeOn() and common resources

Tags: swift, concurrency, rx-swift, reactivex

I have an observable inside a function. 
The function happens in a certain queue, queueA, and the observable is subscribed to with observeOn(schedulerB). In onNext, I'm changing a class variable.

In another function, I'm changing the same class variable, from a different queue.

Here is some code to demonstrate my situation:

```
class SomeClass {

    var commonResource: [String: String] = [:]
    var queueA = DispatchQueue(label: "A")
    var queueB = DispatchQueue(label: "B")
    var schedulerB = ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(queue: QueueB)       

    func writeToResourceInOnNext() {
        let obs: PublishSubject<String> = OtherClass.GetObservable()
        obs.observeOn(schedulerB)
           .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] res in
            // this happens on queue B
            self.commonResource["key"] = res
        }
    }

    func writeToResource() {
        // this happens on queue A
        commonResource["key"] = "otherValue"
    }
}
```

My question is, is it likely to have concurrency issues, if commonResource is modified in both places at the same time?

What is the common practice for writing/reading from class/global variables inside onNext in an observable with observeOn?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Since your `SomeClass` has no control over when these functions will be called or on what threads the answer is yes, you are setup to have concurrency issues in this code due to its passive nature.

The obvious solution here is to dispatch to queue B inside `writeToResource()` in order to avoid the race condition.

Another option would be to use an `NSLock` (or `NSRecursiveLock`) and lock it before you write to the resource and unlock it after.

The best practice is: when you have a side effect happening inside a subscribe function's closure (in this case writing to `commonResource` that the closure is the *only* place where the side effect occurs. This would mean doing away with the passive `writeToResource()` function and instead passing in an Observable that was generated by whatever code currently is calling the function.

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense. I'm not sure I understood your last paragraph though.

Comment: Something calls `writeToResource()` in response to some action. Instead of `SomeClass` passively sitting around waiting for that function to be called, it should be actively subscribing to whatever that event is. In practice, that would probably mean injecting an Observable that represents the action for SomeClass to subscribe to. This isn't something that can be explained well in the context of an SO question. Come join us on https://rxslack.herokuapp.com if you can...